# Whom does msg.sender, from, and to refer to in this swap function?

Tags: solidity, decentralized-exchange

This question is from the Ethernaut Challenge #22: Dex https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/level/0x9CB391dbcD447E645D6Cb55dE6ca23164130D008

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "openzeppelin-contracts-08/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "openzeppelin-contracts-08/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import 'openzeppelin-contracts-08/access/Ownable.sol';

contract Dex is Ownable {
  address public token1;
  address public token2;
  constructor() {}

  function setTokens(address _token1, address _token2) public onlyOwner {
    token1 = _token1;
    token2 = _token2;
  }
  
  function addLiquidity(address token_address, uint amount) public onlyOwner {
    IERC20(token_address).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
  }
  
  function swap(address from, address to, uint amount) public {
    require((from == token1 && to == token2) || (from == token2 && to == token1), "Invalid tokens");
    require(IERC20(from).balanceOf(msg.sender) >= amount, "Not enough to swap");
    uint swapAmount = getSwapPrice(from, to, amount);
    IERC20(from).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
    IERC20(to).approve(address(this), swapAmount);
    IERC20(to).transferFrom(address(this), msg.sender, swapAmount);
  }

  function getSwapPrice(address from, address to, uint amount) public view returns(uint){
    return((amount * IERC20(to).balanceOf(address(this)))/IERC20(from).balanceOf(address(this)));
  }

  function approve(address spender, uint amount) public {
    SwappableToken(token1).approve(msg.sender, spender, amount);
    SwappableToken(token2).approve(msg.sender, spender, amount);
  }

  function balanceOf(address token, address account) public view returns (uint){
    return IERC20(token).balanceOf(account);
  }
}
```

- 1. For the `swap()` function, I know `msg.sender` can refer to the address that deploys the contract or sender of the transaction. But in this case, whom does the `msg.sender` refer to inside the `require()` statements and `transferFrom()` functions? How did you know that?
- 2. Whom does the `from` refer to in the `require()` statements, `getSwapPrice()`, and `IERC20()`? Whom does the `to` refer to in the `require()` statements, `getSwapPrice()`, and `IERC20()`?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it clear, assuming:

- You have and account with address `0x1111...` ,
- There are two tokens: Token A with address `0x2222...`, token B with address `0x3333...`
- You want to swap `100` token A for `X` token B: you call  `swap(0x2222..., 0x3333.., 100)`.

Here, `from` means the token you want to spend (Token A), and `to` means the token you want to receive. Assuming the price is `10 token A = 1 token B`, after the call you spent 100 token A and got 10 token B in return:

1. The msg.sender is always the one who send the transaction or the immediate contract that calls this contract. Deployer can be another unrelated address. In this context, if you call `swap(...` directly, msg.sender will always be your address (i.e. 0x1111....). In short, it means the address that calls this `Dex` contract's `swap` function.
2. As stated above, they have consistent meaning in all those contexts the address `from` = Token A, the token you want to spend in exchange for token B (the address `to`)
3. Related to 1., if you call, say contract C address 0x4444... , and inside that contract C there is a logic to call `swap(...` of the DEX, then msg.sender will be 0x4444...

Read more about msg.sender: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48562483/solidity-basics-what-msg-sender-stands-for

Comment: At first I thought the address of the token A is the same as that of the deployer of the contract since token A belong to the deployer, isn't this how DEX works?

Comment: When you deploy a contract (you are deployer for example), you get a new address (token A) here. To interact with your token you use token A's address. The deployer address doesn't have any meaning after that. In some contracts like `Ownable` above, the `deployer` can be the initial `owner`. But it's a separate matter. Before understanding how DEX work I think it's better to look at how contract deployment and token work first. Dex may have owners or admin, and it can be different from the deployer